# Fatal error: Call to a member function getQntyInput() on null in

Tags: admin, customer, magento1.9.3.1

In **Magento 1.9.3.1** admin customer view got an error -

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getQntyInput() on null in public_html/app/code/community/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Observer/Stock.php on line 164

and that line is

> if (!$productOption->getQntyInput()) continue;

Comment: you should debug `$productOption` variable using `var_dump($productOption)` or `$productOption->debug()`

Comment: var_dump($productOption) its return null value

Comment: thats why you are encountering error, becuase this variable is NULL, you need to debug this variable further why it is NULL in your code

Comment: debug it but its only error for one customer

Comment: so what you have found in this variable for which is working and for which its not working?

Comment: main issue faced at customer view..some customers are viewed perfectly but only one customer has this issue

Comment: yes I have understood your issue. you need to check what value `$productOption`  has for all other customer and what values it has for that particular customer.

Comment: or paste the code of your file .

Comment: its code file is too long

Comment: ok, but you tried to debug that variable in both cases ?

Comment: var_dump($productOption);die("here");
for particular customer its display NULL
for others its not display any value its not die also

Comment: oh well, sounds good. share your fix please

Comment: if ($productOption == NULL) continue;

Comment: yes it is quick  fixed but not recommended one.